# Can't `pip install numpy` with a Python 3.9 venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, python-3.9, more-itertools

I installed Python 3.9, created a `venv` and tried to install numpy. There was an error with Cython, that was fixed in trunk.

So I installed in the venv [Cython 3.0a0](https://github.com/cython/cython) and retried:

> (venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/cython$ pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
>
> [...]
>
> ***Collecting Cython>=0.29.13***
>
> [...]
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   /home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/bin/python3.9
>   /home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
>   install ***--ignore-installed*** --no-user --prefix
>   /tmp/pip-build-env-3ctn3kl8/overlay --no-warn-script-location
>   --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' Check the logs for full command
>   output.

So I tried to comment out `--ignore-installed` in `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py`, in function `def install_requirements`. I get this error:

```py
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 312, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 223, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 49, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 37, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 90, in _setup_isolation
    reqs = backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 151, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 255, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 63, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1016, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 993, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1016, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 993, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

So I installed manually the dependencies and tried with `--no-deps`:

```sh
(venv) marco@buzz:~/sources/tests/more_itertools/venv$ pip install numpy --no-deps
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/0a/5df350c29a06835d534a6c4f5681075304da38d85f1c69e5226a635a67ce/numpy-1.18.0.zip
  Installing build dependencies ... error
[...]
```

and same error as before. `--no-deps` is ignored, and `--ignore-installed` force to download Cython from Pypi, that does not work with Python 3.9.

Apparently, there's no `--no-ignore-installed`, or `--ignore-installed=0`. And the facts that

1. `pip` ignores `--no-deps`
2. if you comment out `--ignore-installed` in the `venv`, `pip` fails to find already installed module

Comment: why are you using python 3.9 already, are you from the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success with the good old `easy_install`, so I think it's good for now. I'll report this bug (to `venv` devs, I guess).

Comment: when i tried this, then i was met with an error saying RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

Comment: @RoaldAndreKvarv Stacktrace?